# how to create parent-child report

Tags: c#, charts, report, mschart

I try to create simple winform report(s) based on table from my database. Because there are many aggregations I want to create one parent chart and optional child chart. 
Below is the core which draws "parent" report

```
private bool DrawReport(DataTable dt)
    {
        string serieName;
        foreach (object itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            serieName = itemChecked.ToString();
            chart1.Series.Add(serieName);
            chart1.Series[serieName].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            //chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        }
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                string X = dr["DATE"].ToString() + "  " + dr["HOUR"].ToString();
                string Y = dr["MED"].ToString();
                try
                {
                    chart1.Series[SER].Points.AddXY(X, Y);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
        }
        chart1.DataBind();
        chart1.Visible = true;
        return true;
    }
```

Until now everything works fine.

As you see X axis labels contains periods of time - in fact 4 or 6 hours periods. 
The point is to create another chart "child one". It would appears when I click on element of serie. So for now question is how to read value of clicked x axis element ( which is in fact string of dates) to variable. I am able to show this value on tooltip

```
chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "#VALX"
```

but I cant find the way to assign it to variable.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download the chart samples from [MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61), as it can help quite a bit with these charts. For your specific problem, you can use `Chart.HitTest` to figure out which charting element the mouse was clicked on (or moved over, etc). Something like (I used this for `MouseMove`, but you can easily adapt it for `MouseClick` or another event):

```
private void ChartMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HitTestResult[] htrList = Chart.HitTest(e.X, e.Y, false, ChartElementType.DataPoint);
            // loop through all of the elements in htrList, and make the "child" chart
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            StatusLabelText = "";
        }
    }
```

If the chart element that was clicked was a `DataPoint`, then you can get the x and/or y value as needed. One thing that you may want to consider: instead of constructing a date representation yourself (`string X = dr["DATE"].ToString() + "  " + dr["HOUR"].ToString();`), you may want to use a `DateTime` object as the x value of the `DataPoint`, and just have the chart format it appropriately for display (chart.AxisX.Format = "mmddyy   hh" in pseudo-code). This will make it easier to match the point when creating the child chart.

One other point: one of your last lines (`chart.DataBind();`) is not needed based on the code presented. You never specify a `DataSource` for the chart, and you add `DataPoints` manually, so data binding is not needed.